# spring testing, how to mock the result of a method call using `@TestConfiguration`

Tags: spring, spock

I have this bean which is used somewhere inside of another bean I try to test. However I can not mock the method call since it always says _ is an unknown property.

```
@TestConfiguration
class IntegrationTestMockingConfig {
    private DetachedMockFactory factory = new DetachedMockFactory()

    @Bean
    CloudStorage s3Client() {
        def mockedS3 = factory.Mock(CloudStorage)
        1 * mockedS3.tempDownload(_) >> {
            log.info("mocked s3 client")
            new File(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("testfiles/regular.zip").toURI())
        }
        mockedS3
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply stub the method in your test's `setup()`-method. You can get the mock via dependency-injection into the test.

Comment: works because it's a singleton. however looks not like the most right solution

Answer (score 0):

Mocking/stubbing outside of a Specification context is not supported. I'd suggest to use the [@SpringBean](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.2/all_in_one.html#_annotation_driven) of Spock 1.2.

```
@SpringBootTest
class MyTest extends Specification {

    @SpringBean
    CloudStorage mockedS3 = Mock() 

    def "test"() {
      when:
      otherBean.otherMethod()

      then:
        1 * mockedS3.tempDownload(_) >> {
               log.info("mocked s3 client")
                new File(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("testfiles/regular.zip").toURI())
        }
    }
}
```